# CSS link not clickable inside table when using float position

Tags: html, css

Link cannot be clicked on the images inside the table

```
<div id="1" class="title_page">
<a href="http://link.com">
<img width="450px" src="img/logo.png">
</a>
</div>
<div id="2" class="game_buttons">
<table class="gb_table" border="0" cellspacing="30" align="right">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://link1.com" target="_blank"><img src="logo1.png"></a></td>
<td><a href="http://link2.com" target="_blank"><img src="logo2.png"></a></td>
<td><a href="http://link3.com" target="_blank"><img src="logo3.png"></a></td>
<td><a href="http://link4.com" target="_blank"><img src="logo4.png"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
div.title_page {
margin-top: 20px;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
}
div.game_buttons {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    z-index:10;
}
```

The problem is in the game_buttons class div

Comment: this is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ffjL/ and no problem to click on those links. Also there is no position absolute visible in the code you show us here.

Comment: i don't understand why wont it work on my page.

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle there is no problem with clicking on those links. there must be something else above them. use firefoxes firebug to insepct your page

Comment: wait ill post the rest of the code

Comment: put page link where it's not working, because in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wwge/) it's working fine.

Comment: Your code is working fine. I don't know what the issue is. Any Fiddle

Comment: check your z-index value of outside "game-buttons" div. may be that cause the issue.

Comment: please check on my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css like below..

```
div.title_page {
margin-top: 20px;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
}
.game_buttons {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
z-index:10;
position:relative;
}
```

Sample JsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGa3w/